# What is the Objective C equivalent of self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, size-classes

What is the obj c code for below swift statement?

```
 if (self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact)
```

what i figured out so far is proviede below but it is giving error when i add `self.view`

```
    if ([self.view UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact])
    {
        NSLog(@"Compact");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Hope it works